# how to migrate the selection provider in e4

Tags: java, eclipse, e4

I'm migrating Eclipse views to using the e4 framework, currently we use Ecipse 4.4.1 in compability mode.

In most views I'm setting the selection provider of the site:

```
site.setSelectionProvider(treeViewer);
```

In different handlers I then use code like this to get the selection:

```
IWorkbenchSite site = HandlerUtil.getActiveSite(event);
ISelectionProvider selectionProvider = site.getSelectionProvider();
ISelection selection = selectionProvider.getSelection();
```

Some handler even use the selection provider and if it is Viewer work with it e.g. refersh, expand...

```
ISelectionProvider selectionProvider = activeSite.getSelectionProvider();
if (selectionProvider instanceof StructuredViewer) {
...
}
```

The wiki describes how to handle selections new in e4.
https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/EAS/Selection

What I can't find is a way to migrate using the actual selection provider?

Comment: There is no selection provider in e4 just a current selection for each part.

Answer (score 2):

In an e4 handler you use something like:

```
@Execute
void execute(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) IStructuredSelection selection
{
  ...
}
```

to get the active selection.

If you want to look at the active part you can use:

```
@Execute
void execute(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART) MPart activePart)
{
  Object object = activePart.getObject();

  // 'object' is the class you defined for the part in the Application.e4xmi
}
```